# No updates for 4 months on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, repository, software-sources

I have been away for 4 months and when I started Ubuntu again there were 0 updates available. That seems very odd to me. I tried several times and always got that the same result: packages are all up to date. How can that be? Any suggestions?

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS - 64-bit - Gnome Version 3.36.8

```
$ sudo apt update
OK:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
OK:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease               
OK:3 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease               
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig           
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Alle Pakete sind aktuell.
```

Comment: 22.04 is around the corner, 4 months with no update is definitely possible. Especially when you seem to have only very few repos enabled. I have security, updates, backports, main, universe in addition to what you have enabled.

Comment: Update the local package information with `sudo apt update` then upgrade the packages with `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Restore default repository, I kinda miss focal-updates and focal-security.  https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Your Ubuntu system did not delete the `focal-updates` and `focal-security` sources itself. Whatever reason you had for disabling/deleting those sources, it was unwise. Restore them, and don't do that again.

Comment: Thanks emk2203, Mark, nobody, user535733 and specially Someone for the copy-past command line. The update works now and the sources are complete. I don't know how the sources got deleted or disabled, make me worried about the safety of my computer. How can I check if my system got compromised?

Comment: @Patrick Awesome! Glad your sources are complete. You can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark button near the votes if you find it useful. I don't think that any application or programme has disabled the sources, it's done by a human being. Maybe you were following some tutorial and blindly ran a few commands in the terminal? Sometimes, while upgrading or updating the repositories are turned off... Are you having the repositories in `sources.list` or did you define a custom path for it? System disables the repositories if they are on custom paths while upgrading certain packages.

Answer (score 12):

There seems to be issues with the repositories. Check if your mirror is up to date. Then follow these steps:

1. Open Software and Updates app.

   ```
   sudo software-properties-gtk
   ```
2. As you want ALL the upgrades, I recommend enabling ALL the repositories:

   [image: Enable all repositories.]
3. Then change the mirror to "Main Server".
4. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Then upgrade:

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

Here is a one line copy-paste friendly command for the above steps:

```
sudo mkdir ~/answer && cd ~/answer/ && sudo wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170/raw/3822ba49241e6fd851ca1c1cbcc4d7e87382f484/sources.list && sudo sed -i "s/focal/$(lsb_release -c -s)/" ~/answer/sources.list && sudo mv ~/answer/sources.list /etc/apt/ && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade  && sudo rm -rf ~/answer
```

Comment: It indeed may well be that all repositories were turned off for one or another reason.